# Group, sum and subtract with conditions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Having the list of objects bellow:

```
public class Example
{
    public string Local { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to group the list by `Local` and, in the same field (**Total**), **sum** the `Amount` where the `Type` is "Input" and **subtract** the `Amount` where the `Type` is "Output".

Example:

[image]

Based on the example above, I want the following results:

[image]

I've tried the following code, but it's not working. It's returning NULL on `Total`.

```
var Balances = Examples
.GroupBy(y => y.Local)
.Select(y => new BalanceDTO
{
    Local = y.FirstOrDefault().Local
    Total = y.Where(z => z.Type == "Input").Sum(z => z.Amount) - y.Where(z => z.Type == "Output").Sum(z => z.Amount)
}).ToList()
```

What should I do?

Comment: `Local = y.Key,`  ...simpler, and clearer as to the intent.

Comment: *"but it's not working"* - Please expand on that. What do you get and how are your expectations not being met?

Comment: @madreflection Added example and more details

Comment: That describes the input, but that much could be assumed based on the description you'd already given. It's just as important to indicate what you *are* getting. Sometimes the difference in actual and expected outputs can make subtle, hard-to-find bugs easier to find.

Comment: @madreflection As I've added, it's returning NULL on Total field.

Comment: I'll admit that I glanced over that part of the edit. However, I don't see how it's possible for `Total` to be `null` if the `Amount` is not nullable in the first place. The `Sum` calls will accumulate `Account` and return `int`, and the subtraction will also yield `int`. There's nothing nullable there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added a computed property to your `Example` class:

```
public class Example
{
    public string Local { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int NetAmount
    {
        get
        {
            return Type == "Input" ? Amount : -1 * Amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your LINQ group them on the `Local` field as you did, and then I've used the [LINQ Aggregate method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate) to sum all of these 'net totals' in each group:

```
var Balances = Examples
    .GroupBy(y => y.Local)
    .Select(y => new
    {
        Local = y.Key,
        Total = y.Sum(y => y.NetAmount)
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! It works if I enumarate the results before using ``Aggregate``, but is there a simmilar to ``Aggregate`` using LINQ to Entities?

Comment: Not that I know of sorry @Taian, I think you always have to enumerate the results into memory first.  Sorry.

Comment: Note that your aggregate could be written as `Total = y.Sum(item => item.NetAmount)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative solution:

```
 var Balances = Examples.GroupBy(
                y => y.Local, 
                y => (y.Type, y.Amount), 
                (key,elements) => new { 
                    Local = key, 
                    Total = elements.Sum(el => el.Type == "Input" ? el.Amount : -el.Amount) 
                });
```